# String as reference argument

Tags: c++, arguments

I'm beginning with C++ and I'm not sure about one thing...

Is this code ok or there is some problem?

```
void foo(const std::string& data)
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

foo("Hello World");
```

I'm really not sure about this but I think that when calling function `foo`, temporary string variable will be created, then its reference will be passed as an argument and then this temporary variable gets destroyed. So function `foo` will try to access deleted memory which is undefined behaviour. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary generally extends until the *end of the full expression* in which it appears, which is usually a semicolon.

The full expression in which your temporary is needed is `foo("Hello World")`, and so the temporary string lives for the entire duration of the function call, and all is well.